# How to autofill based on values in multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

First question, hope I'm doing this right...

I've got a series of data in Cells A:C
Let's take for instance:

- *Cell A2* = Apple
- *Cell B2* = Banana
- *Cell C3* = Tomato

Within **Cell D3** I'd like to have it *Autofill* as 'Fruit'. If any cells from A:C are not one of those selection, return blank.
The aim is to have drop down lists for cells A:C and return certain values based on the combination of these. How would this easily be possible using VBA instead of formulas?

I'm able to do this for single cells, never multiple.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've tagged this question with VBA, so please, post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below code i use **Step 2** which test values every two rows. you can remove it if you want to test every line.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, Row As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For Row = 2 To LastRow Step 2

            If .Range("A" & Row).Value = "Apple" Or .Range("A" & Row).Value = "Banana" Or .Range("A" & Row).Value = "Tomato" Then
                If .Range("B" & Row).Value = "Apple" Or .Range("B" & Row).Value = "Banana" Or .Range("B" & Row).Value = "Tomato" Then
                    If .Range("C" & Row + 1).Value = "Apple" Or .Range("C" & Row + 1).Value = "Banana" Or .Range("C" & Row + 1).Value = "Tomato" Then
                        .Range("D" & Row + 1).Value = "Fruits"
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Else
                Exit For
            End If

        Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```